# script bat para reiniciar onedrive. Será que funciona?

Tags: cmd, batch, bat, onedrive

O cenário é que tenho alguns computadores sem interação de usuário aonde uso o **OneDrive** para fazer backup de madrugada

Com certa frequência o **OneDrive** trava, então resolvi fazer um `bat`, bem simples, para verificar se ele travou e reiniciar ele.

Antes de testar resolvi postar, de repente deixei passar alguma bobagem e/ou para caso de alguém tenha alguma sugestão de melhoria, ou venha ter utilidade para alguém.

```bat
@echo off
:inicio
set fiscaliza=nul

tasklist /fi "status eq not responding" >c:\bat\fiscaliza.txt
find /i "certisignergui.exe" "c:\bat\fiscaliza.txt"

if  %errorlevel% equ 0 ( 

   set datadehoje=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%  %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%
   echo %datadehoje%>>c:\bat\travada_onedrive.txt

   taskkill /im certisignergui.exe /f

   echo finalizando processo travado
   del "fiscaliza.txt"

  ) else (

   echo processo nao travou ainda

  )

  timeout /t 10
  goto inicio
```

Esse é o primeiro teste que fiz, meu objetivo foi só verificar se ele achava e fechava o programa travado, nos primeiros testes deu certo. Coloquei o `timeout` como 10 segundos, mas a ideia é que rode a cada uns 900 segundos.

Comment: Fala aí, colega. Isso não é, necessariamente, uma pergunta. O mais interessante é você fazer uma pergunta e **depois** [responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Tudo que você precisa saber sobre isso está nesse link da central de ajuda. Outra dica é sobre [formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). ;)

Comment: É não estava claro, obrigado, editei.

Comment: Parece que você "tentou" transformar um "script que quer compartilhar" em uma pergunta. Raciocine um instante: qual a sua pergunta? Se for "***Será que funciona?***" não segue o escopo do site. Você deve fazer perguntas sobre "problemas reais"... Se o objetivo é buscar "melhoras no seu script", defina explicitamente "como e/ou o quê você quer melhorar".

Answer (score 4):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> *• Para ficar em loop durante **10 segundos** monitorando se há travamento e reiniciando sempre que **OneDrive** figurar em travamento*:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d c:\bat
set DataDeHoje=0<nul & echo/ & Title %~n0 & mode con cols=60 lines=03 & >nul chcp 1252 
set _key="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
for /f ^delims^=^"^ ^tokens^=2^,*  %%i in ('reg query !_key! ^| findstr /lic:"onedrive"') do set "_OneDrive="%%i" %%j"
:inicio
echo/ & color 9F & set "DataDeHoje=!DATE:~0,2!-!DATE:~3,2!-!DATE:~6,4!/!time:~0,5!"&&set "DataDeHoje=!DataDeHoje: =0!"
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%i in ('tasklist /fi "status eq not responding" ^| findstr /v "# ="') do (
echo/%%i %%j | findstr /lic:"OneDrive.exe" >"c:\bat\fiscaliza.txt" && (
color F4 & echo/ & echo/ !DataDeHoje:/= ! Processo: OneDrive.exe travado^^!!.. & taskkill /f /im %%i /t >nul 2>nul
start "" !_OneDrive! && pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 2500 1>nul & tasklist /fi "status eq running" | findstr /lic:"onedrive.exe" >nul
if "!errorlevel!" equ "0" color 9F & cls & echo/ !DataDeHoje:/= ! Processo: OneDrive.exe reiniciado^^!!..
   ) || (
    cls & echo/ & echo/ !DataDeHoje:/= ! Processo: OneDrive.exe sem travamento^^!!..
   )) & timeout /t 10 >nul & goto :inicio
```

---

• É possível um **bat/script** assumir essas ações. Mas, eu lhe sugiro usar o argumento **`/T`**, que resulta em **finalizar** os possíveis **terceiros processos** startados/iniciados por ele também, visto, que o travamento possa ocorrer por conta um desse mesmos **processos** por ele **inicializadas**...

---

> ### • Só monitorar!! Não assume acão alguma!!

*• Para ficar em loop durante **10 segundos** monitorando se há travamento do* **OneDrive.exe**:

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d c:\bat
set DataDeHoje=0<nul & echo/ & Title %~n0 & mode con cols=60 lines=03 & >nul chcp 1252
:inicio
echo/ & color 9F & set "DataDeHoje=!DATE:~0,2!-!DATE:~3,2!-!DATE:~6,4!/!time:~0,5!"&&set "DataDeHoje=!DataDeHoje: =0!"
for /f "tokens=1,*delims= " %%i in ('tasklist /fi "status eq not responding" ^| findstr /v "# ="')do (
echo/%%i %%j | findstr /lic:"OneDrive.exe" >"c:\bat\fiscaliza.txt" && (
color F4 & echo/ & echo/ !DataDeHoje:/= ! Processo: OneDrive.exe travado^^!!.. & taskkill /f /im %%i >nul 2>nul 
   ) || (
   echo/ !DataDeHoje:/= ! Processo: OneDrive.exe sem travamento^^!!..
   )) & timeout /T 10 >nul & cls & goto :inicio
```

---

> ### • Só monitorar!! Não assume acão alguma!!

*• Para ficar em loop durante **10 segundos** monitorando se há travamento de outro* **Qualquer_Outro_Programa.exe**:

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d c:\bat
set DataDeHoje=0<nul & echo/ & Title %~n0 & mode con cols=60 lines=03 & >nul chcp 1252
:inicio
echo/ & color 9F & set "DataDeHoje=!DATE:~0,2!-!DATE:~3,2!-!DATE:~6,4!/!time:~0,5!"&&set "DataDeHoje=!DataDeHoje: =0!"
for /f "tokens=1,*delims= " %%i in ('tasklist /fi "status eq not responding" ^| findstr /v "# ="')do (
echo/%%i %%j | findstr /lic:".exe" >"c:\bat\fiscaliza.txt" && (
color F4 & echo/ & echo/ !DataDeHoje:/= ! Processo: %%i travado^^!!.. & taskkill /f /im %%i >nul 2>nul 
  ) || (
  echo/ !DataDeHoje:/= ! Todos os processos sem travamento^^!!..
  )) & timeout /T 10 >nul & cls & goto :inicio
```

---